# How to get first childnode within a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, nodelist

I'm trying to create a script that gets all the sections of documentation and creates a navigation with the id for a link and the H2 as the link text. I've tried several ways and the title is undefined. I've tried using a class, getting the first child node, and converting the nodelist to an array.

http://codepen.io/brooksroche/pen/XmpNaq?editors=101

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName("doc-section")) {
  var sections = document.getElementsByClassName("doc-section"),
    sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebarNav'),
    navLinks = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; ++i) {
    var current = sections[i],
      anchorID = current.id,
      title = current.childNodes[0].text,
      navLink = '<li><a href="#' + anchorID + '">' + title + '</a></li>',
      navLinks = navLinks + navLink;
  }
  if (sidebar) {
    sidebar.innerHTML = navLinks;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead (when collecting headers):

```
title = current.children[0].textContent
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbyVYw?editors=101). In other words, you should place `children` instead of `childNodes`, as with the latter both elements and text nodes are collected. Quoting [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes):

> childNodes also includes e.g. text nodes and comments. To skip them,
>   use `ParentNode.children` instead.

In this particular case, whitespace between closing  tag and opening  tag was actually the first `childNode` of section element. You were able to get its text with `.data` property, but it was obviously of no use.

Actually, you might consider this as a safer alternative:

```
title = current.querySelector('.sectionTitle').textContent
```

... so that when the corresponding element's order is changed, you'll still be able to collect the text from it (if class is the same, of course).